# How do I bind the current user session to a dynamic var using Clojure Friend library?

Tags: authentication, clojure

I am using the [Friend Authentication Library](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) for Clojure to add HTTP basic auth to my webapp.

I have a set of database access functions in a `db.clj` module that abstracts away the current user so I can invoke methods like `(db/get-item ...)` for example to retrieve an item for the current user without explicitly specifying the user.  I do this by defining a dynamic var called `*username*`.  This allows me to easily test the database access functions at the REPL for different users, then the webapp code can rebind `*username*` to the session user for when it calls the db functions.

I need to bind `*username*` to the user for the current session so that whenever the functions in `db.clj` are accessed from a web server request, the `*username*` var is set properly.

I can get the session username from `((friend/current-authentication) :username)` but I can't figure out where I can hook this into the web-server code.  I have a simple middleware:

```
(defn wrap-username [app]
  (fn [req]
    (binding [*username* (friend/current-authentication :username)]
      (app req))))
```

But no matter where I call this middleware from, `current-authentication` always returns `nil`.

I am trying to understand how the friend authentication code works in order to determine the correct place to do my binding but so far I haven't figured it out.

Comment: Are you including `friend/authenticate` in your middleware stack?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the way you are calling `current-authentication` is incorrect as the documentation says you need to pass the current request to this function, so it should be something like:

```
(binding [*username* ((friend/current-authentication req) :username)] ...
```

Also make sure the friend middleware is applied before your username middleware.